# Word 2007 Forms - Plain Text Control does not accept unless you Tab

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, forms

I am having an issue where I have created a form in Word 2007.  It is a combination of Radio boxes, ActiveX Text Box controls, and Word 2007 Plain Text Controls.

However, the issue that I'm having is that when I restrict the document for editing, only allowing "Filling in forms", I've found that when I open the document, it doesn't let me type in the Word 2007 Plain Text Controls.  The only way to do so is to tab from just before the control.

Has anyone seen this before?  If so, is there some way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer over at Microsoft's forums.  "Filling out forms" doesn't really work well with the newer Word 2007 controls.  Instead of using a Mix of ActiveX and Word 2007 controls, I replace them all with Word 2007 controls and "grouped them", which is the Word 2007 equivalent of "Filling out from" protection